# Guardar imagenes en memoria cache para no volverlas a descargar

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

Buen día.

Tengo una serie de imágenes en mi `Activity`, cada vez que ingreso a esta `Activity` descarga las imágenes, por lo que yo considero que esta "mal", estuve leyendo sobre el *consumo de recursos* de las imágenes pero no me quedo muy claro, agradecería que me ayudaran con un ejemplo para tener un poco mas claro este concepto.

Para la descarga de imágenes estoy utilizando Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Estas usando GLIDE o PICCASO para cargar tus imágenes?. Te sugiero que incluyas tu código cuando cargas tus imágenes ...

Answer (score 4):

En el caso de usar `Picasso` o `Glide` se puede usar un callback detectando la carga de la imagen en el `ImageView`, al cargar la imagen podemos crear un archivo para guardar:

```
//Picasso.with(ctx).load("http://mydominio.com/my_imagen.png").into(getTarget(url)); 

Picasso.get().load("http://mydominio.com/my_imagen.png").into(getTarget(url));
```

Este sería el método:

```
//Metodo para salvar el target.
private static Target getTarget(final String url){
    Target target = new Target(){

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + url);
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                        ostream.flush();
                        ostream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
    return target;
}
```

Se puede ver esto en la respuesta de [@FernandoNaiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483084/fernandopaiva)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32799659/250260

Comment: Recomiendo de usar almacenamiento interno en general sobre almacenamiento externo excepto en casos en que se trata de apps que gestionan almacenamiento de archivos y datos. Existe la opción de migrar el almacenamiento interno al almacenamiento externo para apps del lado del sistema.

Comment: Una duda, en la siguiente linea del code **Picasso.with(ctx).** que es **ctx** , es el context que se obtiene por *getContext()* o *getActivity()*

Comment: Hola @CristianBudzicz , así es, pero con la actual versión solo necesitas usar el método get() sin el contexto, he editado mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias! Ahí le dí me gusta a tu respuesta! Saludos!

Comment: Gracias a tí @CristianBudzicz por apoyar mis respuestas, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar un `Bitmap` en la memoria puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
FileOutputStream fos = null;
getFilesDir().mkdirs("cache"); // crear carpeta para cache si no existe 
try {
    fos = openFileOutput("cache/DvpvklR.png");
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

remplaza las rutas fijas por variables según tus necesidades.

Comment: out siempre es null?

Comment: oops, cambíé el nombre de la variable entremedio. Lo voy a corregir. Perdon.